# textarea focus event takes place so many times unwantedly in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Pretty simple JS:

```
$(".input").focus(function(){

    alert("input clicked");

});
```

HTML:

```
<textarea class="input"  style="height:20px" cols="60"></textarea>
```

In Chrome so many alerts are received but in FF, all is ok.

If I use 'click', instead of 'focus', then in Chrome, focusing the textarea very gently launches no alert box but it does get focused. I tested the focusing with some default text getting changed (not mentioned in the code).

I want to make a status update box just like Facebook. When the user focuses the textarea, it will expand horizontally with new content.

What is the way that Chrome and all other browsers will behave in the same way (producing the alert only once)?

Comment: How many alerts is 'so many' in Chrome (infinite?). Also, what do you mean by focussing very 'gently'?

Comment: got more than 30 alerts.Through 'gently', i wanted to mean that only focusing but not clicking.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it might be like this: You click in the textarea, it is focused and the event listener is invoked. The alert box is shown resulting in the textarea losing its focus for the  time the box is shown. When you dismiss the alert box, the textarea gets focused and the event listener is invoked again.

If this is the case and Chrome is the only browser behaving this way, it might be a good idea to file a bug report.

Update: And to address your problem. Are you sure you need the alert box? It is usually a bad idea and use of some other (non-blocking) alerting mechanism is preferred.

From what I understand, you don't need the box. Just expand the textarea instead of showing the alert box. And use `console.log` for debugging.

Comment: In the FF like, update status box, alert is not necessary but in other cases that might be necessary

Comment: And what is the purpose of the alert box? If I focus a textarea and an alert pops up, I, as a user, would be pretty confused. Could you elaborate on this a bit more?

Comment: the issue is with the alert box being shown repeatedly. I was talking about a different situation.. by the way... can't shed light on that just now.. hope to inform later

Answer (score 0):

I would speculate that there is a slight bug in the way Chrome handles alert boxes. When you focus on the textarea, it triggers the alert box, which immediately gains focus (thereby taking focus from the textarea). When you click "OK" to dismiss the alert, the textarea regains focus, but in Chrome, it appears to trigger the `focus`  event again, causing a UI loop.

This only seems to happen if you fire an alert box. If you replace your alert with `console.log("input clicked")` (for example), you will see in the JS console that the event is firing only once. Using `focus` will work fine for what you want to accomplish; you've just uncovered a strange browser bug.

**Edit**

If you *have* to use an alert box, try:

```
var alerted = false;
$(".input").focus(function() {
  if(!alerted) {
    alert("input clicked");
    alerted = true;
  }
});
```

This will only fire once, but for the lifetime of the page (or until you set `alerted` to `false`), which might also not be the desired behaviour. It is recommended to use `console.log` for debugging purposes, and avoid `alert` in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `click` event instead of `focus` event like this example...

```
<textarea rows="3" class="input" style="height: 20px" cols="60"></textarea>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            $(".input").click(function () {
                alert("input clicked");
                $(this).focus();
            });
        </script>
```

and now it works successfully in all browsers....

Comment: Unless you tab into the textarea. It'll be fine with a label, but not tabs.